# How to refresh jLabel in java swing?

Tags: swing, repaint

I am connecting to XMPP Server and in my form I would like to inform a user about current state of operation, i.e. "Connecting to XMPP Server", "Passing authentication", etc. I have following code in java, but it only shows the last state, which is "Successfully connected".

```
private void jLoginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        Connection connection=new XMPPConnection("example.com");
        jStatusBar.setText("Connecting to XMPP Server ...");
        connection.connect();
        jStatusBar.setText("Passing authentication ...");
        connection.login(username, password);
        jStatusBar.setText("Successfully connected.");

}
```

How to make java to refresh labels?

Comment: *Where* is this snippit of code located in your swing application? If it's in an event handler, the first two will never show because you're in the thread that's also responsible for handling repaint events.

Comment: @BrianRoach. It is under the click event of a jButton. I have updated the code block above.

Answer (score 0):

You could perform the login in another thread (not in EDT) using SwingWorker and update your status bar in the EDT (using SwingUtilities.invokeLater). Your implementation would look something like this:

```
SwingWorker<Void, Void> loginTask = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>(){

        protected void doInBackground(){
            Connection connection=new XMPPConnection("example.com");
            message( "Connecting to XMPP Server" );
            connection.connect();
            message( "Passing authentication ..." );
            connection.login(username, password);
            message( "Successfully connected." );
        }

        private void message(final String text){
             SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
                 jStatusBar.setText( text );
             });
        }
    }

loginTask.execute();
```

Comment: <anonymous gap.LoginForm$5> is not abstract and does not override abstract method doInBackground() in javax.swing.SwingWorker

Comment: -1 for the detour with invokeLater. The intended way to process intermediate results is to call publish in doInBackground and implement process to do the actual setting (it's guaranteed to be on the EDT)